# Turning a countable set into a doubly or multidimensional array

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. What is the name for the technique  that turns a countable set $\{x_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ into a
   doubly array $(x_{i,j})_{i, j \in \mathbb{N}}$? It isn't "Cantor argument", is it? Because Cantor
   argument is taking diagonal elements from a given doubly array.

   An example is constructing a $\mathbb{N}$-indexed sequence of i.i.d.
   uniform random variables uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ from a
   $\mathbb{N}$-indexed sequence of i.i.d. random variables Bernoulli
   and uniformly distributed in $\{0,1\}$
2. Is it that a countable set $\{x_n, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ can be turned into a d-dimensional
   array  $(x_{i_1,\dots, i_d})_{i_k \in \mathbb{N}, k=1,\dots, d}$, if and only if the number $d$ of dimensions is countable? How is such transformation done?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: What do you mean "doubly array"? Each point is replaced by a sequence?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: See my edit plz.

Comment: Your 2. is true, provided we have a countably infinite set.

Comment: @Berci: you mean the set $\{x_n\}$ is countably infinite? Is it true when the set is finite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb{N\times N}$, which is essentially taking a countable set and turning it into a countable$^2$ matrix.

This has nothing to do with Cantor's diagonal argument, but it does have to do with Cantor's **pairing function**. We usually say that we encode $\mathbb{N\times N}$, or that we encode tuples, or so on. Of course if this can be done for $\mathbb N$ then it can be done for every countably infinite set.

As for the second question, the answer is yes, clearly if you want the array to have uncountably many entires on one of the indices then a countable set is no longer sufficient; and the above shows that we can generate a countable array easily.

If by "countable dimension" you mean repeat replacing each point by an array of a lower dimension, then the answer is *less* than countably infinite dimensions. Because a countably infinite dimension would correspond to $\mathbb{N^N}$ rather than $\mathbb{N\times N}$, and the former is already uncountable.